# Firebase error v8.9.2 - TypeError: instance.INTERNAL.registerComponent is not a function at register Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am getting the above error with the following code. Anybody come across this before? I've removed the DB name for posting the question?

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("../firebaseprivatekey.json");

var app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://DBNAMEHERE.firebaseio.com"
});

var db = admin.database();
```

Comment: Looks like there's an old version of `@firebase/app` installed in your project. Do you declare such a version explicitly? If not I'd simply try deleting the `node_modules` directory and the package lock files, and reinstalling `firebase-admin`.

Comment: No, i can't see any old references within the package lock files. I have just tried deleting all the firebase references out of the node modules and removed the package lock files. I have then reinitialised the firebase functions folder where this is happening. The interesting bit is version 8.6 has installed and not 8.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install @firebase/app --save
```

Fix my problem as mentioned https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/722#issuecomment-567427306

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this in the end my reverting to using the firebase app sdk instead of the firebase admin SDK and this appeared to resolve the problem. I suspect Hiranya is ultimately right that there is a problem with the firebase installation versions somewhere.